# How to add a placeholder in CKEditor 5?

Tags: placeholder, ckeditor5

```
import BalloonEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor';

import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';

BalloonEditor
                .create( elem, {
                    plugins: [ Markdown, Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic ],
                    toolbar: [ 'bold' ]
                })
                .then((editor) => {
                    ....
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error );
                } );
```

I tried to use **attachPlaceholder** from https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_placeholder.html#static-function-attachPlaceholder

```
import { attachPlaceholder } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder";
```

Could you show me simple example how to use this method (attachPlaceholder) or how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

In `CKEditor-5` you can add `placeholder` like

```
  <ckeditor [config]="{ placeholder:'Placeholder Text', toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList' ] }">
  </ckeditor>
```

[See docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#setting-the-placeholder)

Comment: Is there any way to add line breaks to placeholders? I've tried multiple ways, but it does not work!

Comment: @Shiraaz do you already success create please holder with new line in ckeditor5

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to add a placeholder to the entire editor, so that when it's empty you can display something like "Type here...".

Unfortunately, the `attachPlaceholder()` function doesn't yet support setting placeholder for the editor's main editable. For now, it's used in cases like image captions:

[image: Screenshot of an editable's placeholder in an empty image caption]

There's a ticket to implement configurable editor's placeholders: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/479.

And there's a 3rd party addon which adds a placeholder in a simpler way: https://github.com/alexeckermann/ckeditor5-emptyness.

Answer (score 0):

**Plugin URL** : https://github.com/alexeckermann/ckeditor5-emptyness

Simply build your editor with this plugin and you will get access to a isEmpty observable attribute (care of Observable) on your editor instance. Additionaly, the plugin will add a ck-editor__is-empty class name on the editor element when is is empty.

The origin use case was for the application to observe the attribute and know when the editor enters or exits an empty state. From there the application applies an attribute to the editors HTML element so that a CSS based placeholder can be applied — using CSS's ::before rules to inject phantom content without disturbing CKEditor's actual content.

```
import BalloonEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor- 
balloon/src/ballooneditor';
import Emptyness from 'ckeditor5-emptyness/src/emptyness';
// .. all your other imports here

 export default class MyEditor extends BalloonEditorBase { }

MyEditor.build = {
// ... all your other configs here

plugins: [
    // ... all your other plugins here
    Emptyness
 ]

};
```

CSS

```
.ck-editor__is-empty .ck-content.ck-editor__editable::before,
.ck-editor__is-empty.ck-content.ck-editor__editable::before {
content: 'The editor is empty';
position: absolute;
display: block;

margin: var(--ck-spacing-large) 0;

color: #aaa;
 }
```